# Decorator that can interact with the wrapped function's arguments

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to build a decorator that can inspect the wrapped function's arguments, the context for the need is to allow easier validation of certain arguments before they hit the function, avoiding the boiler plate of checking in every place I need said check/validation.

This is not a difficult decorator to write though, and this gets the job done (to make sure a value is not None for example):

```
def check_arg(func):
    def wrapped(value):
        assert value is not None
        func(value)
    return wrapped
```

The above example is not production code, it is merely an example of something that will work, but the problem becomes apparent when the function to decorate can have other decorators being used.

In that case, the above decorator example will not work, because `value` can now be another decorator. I could add another nested function here but it looks like there should be a better way of dealing with it programmatically, plus, it would break whenever the number of decorators change.

How could I get to the arguments of the wrapped function regardless of the number of decorators used by it?

EDIT: I should've noted than I am not simply stacking decorators, I am using one decorator that decorates re-usable decorators. In the example above I would re-use that in this context:

```
@check_arg
def some_other_decorator(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kw):
        ... # some interaction here
    return wrapped
```

As I was writing this edit, I realized that the `check_arg` decorator was in the wrong place, it should've been in the `wrapped` function call within the `some_other_decorator`.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused; isn't `value` always going to be an argument that the user supplied? `func` might be a function that has already been processed by another decorator, but it will still be a function that expects the same type of argument as `wrapped`, or the call to `func` inside `wrapped` won't work. Could you supply an example of code where your prototype fails?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in control of the other decorators? If so, make sure all of them play nice by properly 
wrapping the calling function:

```
  import functools
  def check_arg(func):
      @functools.wraps(func)
      def wrapped(value):
          assert value is not None
          func(value)
      return wrapped
```